# The meaning of cable should be wound around cylindrical ferrite

Tags: circuit-design, cables

What is the purpose and meaning of a cable wound around and passed through a cylindrical ferrite, that black non-conductive ceramic metal ?

Comment: Ferrite is not a metal alloy, it's a ceramic.

Comment: Its a called a choke which is an inductor with a lossy core material used to suppress noise.

Comment: It’s a ferric metallic  ceramic mixture with more metallic particles for UHF parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Ferrite clamp is called a cable lossy Common-Mode choke for the VHF band.  This is different than a differential ferrite bead for a single wire.  There are some CM chokes that you will find on all VGA cables molded in the cable for RGB video DAC harmonics.

It is a slurry mixture of ceramic capacitance, Zinc oxide with either manganese or Nickel to form a ceramic metallic magnetic material that conducts with a lossy series resistance.

The equivalent circuit is a parallel RLC circuit with a series R that has this effect on a pair of wires to Raise the impedance of both wires at RF so they become more balanced and while absorbing RF somewhere along the cable, the balancing of raised impedance in RF makes the EMI in/out attenuated alot more in that band.

**But not all ferrites are created equal.**

### Reference material

https://incompliancemag.com/article/all-ferrite-beads-are-not-created-equal-understanding-the-importance-of-ferrite-bead-material-behavior/

https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2020-selecting-ferrite-chokes-and-clamps-to-minimize-rfi-and-resistance

[image]
[image]
credits: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ferrite-beads-demystified.html

Answer (score 1):

Ferrite chokes are made of a lossy ferromagnetic material. Intended to absorb radio signals of a certain frequency range, they are often used by equipment manufacturers as an inexpensive or last-ditch effort to make their product EMI-compliant.

Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) courtesy of [Stwalkerster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Stwalkerster) CC BY-SA 3.0
[View citation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cable_end.JPG)
[image: A ferrite bead at the end of a Mini USB cable]